# What is the meaning of Intellij node_modules folder colors?

Tags: intellij-idea, npm

What is the meaning of those node_modules folder colors ?

[image]

How would those folder be differents when they were all installed using  npm ?

More broadly how can we view meta-data associated to a folder ? To understand what is going on.

Comment: See [Configuring node_modules library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_libraries_examples_node_modules) related documentation. The modules, in that folder which are listed in the package.json file - are not marked as Excluded and are used for auto-completion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The grey folders appear to be direct dependencies listed in your package.json, while the orange folders are indirectly required.

Comment: And where is this documented that the "dimmed" (not used, not important) means direct dependency whereas "bright orange" (look at me, I'm important) means indirect? Has somebody sent IntelliJ a link to the concept of tool tips and the amount of documentation and searching that can save?

Answer (score 6):

Orange is the color for excluded folders.  IntelliJ excludes indirect dependencies automatically as you shouldn't be importing those.  Also, having the indirect dependencies excluded also speeds up the search.

The gray is for a basic folder that is not a source folder, excluded ...

FYI, the meta data for the libraryFolder is in the .iml for your project, such as:

```
   <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/dist" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/nbproject" />
      <libraryFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/node_modules" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/node" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/npm-cache" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/wmsWebUi/target" />
    </content>
```

For a complete listing of the file colors see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html?_ga=2.259757642.1179276042.1586287143-485769907.1519135476